# can't reach Fargate task behind load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate

I am unable to reach a Fargate task behind an elb load balancer. The webpage loads super slow and eventually it says can not open the page. When I deploy the ECS task without the LoadBalancer and try to access it using it's private ip and port 8501, it seems to work though. Do I maybe need to switch the internet gateway to a nat gateway?

Can somebody maybe spot why that is the case based on my Terraform code:

Thanks a lot.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "seismic-project-vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
    
  tags = {
    Name = "seismic-project-vpc"
  }
}
    
resource "aws_subnet" "seismic-subnet" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.seismic-project-vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "${var.aws_region}a"
    
  tags = {
    Name = "seismic-subnet"
  }
}
    
resource "aws_security_group" "project_security_group" {
  name_prefix = "project-security-group"
    
  ingress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = "-1"
    self = true
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 3000
    to_port     = 3000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [var.my_ip]
  }
  ingress {
    protocol         = "tcp"
    from_port        = 8501
    to_port          = 8501
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
    
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.seismic-project-vpc.id
}
    
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "seismic_internet_gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.seismic-project-vpc.id
}
    
resource "aws_route_table" "seismic_route_table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.seismic-project-vpc.id  
}
    
resource "aws_route" "route" {
  route_table_id         = aws_route_table.seismic_route_table.id
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id             = aws_internet_gateway.seismic_internet_gateway.id
}
    
resource "aws_route_table_association" "seismic_route_table_association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.seismic-subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.seismic_route_table.id
}
    
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_role" {
  name = "ecs_role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version: "2012-10-17",
      Statement: [
      {
        Effect: "Allow",
        Principal: {
          Service: "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        },
        Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  })
}
 
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_db_policy" {
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.dynamodb_policy_read_only.arn
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_role.name
}
    
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_execution_role" {
  name = "MyEcsExecutionRole"
    
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
      Statement = [
        {
           Effect = "Allow",
           Principal = {
             Service = "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
           },
           Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
  })
}
    
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_execution_attachment" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_execution_role.name
}
    
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_cw_attachment" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchFullAccess"
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_execution_role.name
}
    
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_sm_attachment" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/SecretsManagerReadWrite"
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_execution_role.name
}
    
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.seismic-project-vpc.id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.2.0/24"
  availability_zone       = "${var.aws_region}a"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name = "frontend-subnet"
  }
}
    
resource "aws_subnet" "public2" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.seismic-project-vpc.id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.3.0/24"
  availability_zone       = "${var.aws_region}b"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name = "frontend-subnet-2"
  }
}
    
resource "aws_security_group" "alb" {
  name   = "load-balancer-sg"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.seismic-project-vpc.id  
     
  ingress {
    protocol         = "tcp"
    from_port        = 80
    to_port          = 80
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
     
  egress {
    protocol         = "-1"
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
}
    
resource "aws_lb" "main" {
  name               = "frontend-lb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.alb.id]
  subnets            = [aws_subnet.public.id, aws_subnet.public2.id]
     
  enable_deletion_protection = false
}
     
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "main" {
  name        = "frontend-lb-tg"
  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.seismic-project-vpc.id
  target_type = "ip"
}
    
resource "aws_alb_listener" "http" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.main.arn
  port              = 80
  protocol          = "HTTP"
     
  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.main.arn
    type             = "forward"
  }
}
    
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "ecs_target" {
  max_capacity       = 2
  min_capacity       = 1
  resource_id        = "service/${aws_ecs_cluster.seismic_cluster.name}/${aws_ecs_service.main.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
}
    
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "ecs_policy_memory" {
  name               = "memory-autoscaling"
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id        = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.scalable_dimension
  service_namespace  = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.service_namespace
     
  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ECSServiceAverageMemoryUtilization"
    }
    target_value       = 90
  }
}
    
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "seismic_cluster" {
  name = "seismic-ecs-cluster"
}
    
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "earthquake_frontend_task" {
  family                   = "frontend"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = 256
  memory                   = 512
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs_execution_role.arn
  task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.ecs_role.arn
  container_definitions = jsonencode([{
    name        = "frontend-container"
    image       = "${var.account_id}.dkr.ecr.${var.aws_region}.amazonaws.com/earthquake-frontend:latest"
    essential   = true
    network_mode = "awsvpc"
      portMappings = [{
        protocol      = "tcp"
        containerPort = 8501
        hostPort      = 8501
      }]
  }])
}
    
resource "aws_ecs_service" "main" {
  name                               = "earthquake-frontend-service"
  cluster                            = aws_ecs_cluster.seismic_cluster.id
  task_definition                    = aws_ecs_task_definition.earthquake_frontend_task.arn
  launch_type                        = "FARGATE"
  scheduling_strategy                = "REPLICA"
     
  network_configuration {
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.project_security_group.id]
    subnets          = [aws_subnet.seismic-subnet.id]
    assign_public_ip = true
  }
     
  load_balancer {
     target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.main.arn
     container_name   = "frontend-container"
     container_port   = 8501
  }
  
  depends_on = [
    aws_alb_target_group.main
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `"aws_alb_target_group" "main"` port setting to match your container's port `8501`. Your target group's health checks are almost certainly failing right now, and this change should hopefully be enough to get them passing, but if not you may need to modify the target group's health check settings as well.

Once that is resolved, you should be able to connect via the load balancer's DNS name.

As a side note, it is unclear why you are opening port `3000` in the application's security group, since it only listens on port `8501`.

Comment: I am opening port 3000 for another service in the same subnet, which I want to connect to via my own machine. I have now placed the private subnet behind a nat gateway and was able to resolve the connection issues with the load balancer. However I can not reach the ec2 instance on port 3000 within the private  subnet anymore via it's public IP. do you maybe know why?

Comment: "I have now placed the private subnet behind a nat gateway and was able to resolve the connection issues with the load balancer." That honestly makes no sense, because the load balancer and NAT gateway are never involved in the same connections. But glad you got it working somehow.

Comment: "However I can not reach the ec2 instance on port 3000 within the private subnet anymore via it's public IP." You changed the subnet from public (route to an internet gateway) to private (route to a nat gateway), so now that other service is no longer public (exposed to the Internet). You really need to separate out your services into their own subnets, and their own security groups.

Comment: @MarkB i think i have the same problem. I have implemented just like you suggested but the domain is dead while the load balancer DNS name + backend works. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77483541/route53-ecs-fargate-load-balancer-this-site-cant-be-reached