# Route53 – ECS Fargate Load Balancer – "This site can't be reached"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm trying to attach my ECS Fargate Load Balancer to Route53 but the domain is dead.

Load Balancer DNS name works perfectly fine. It's healthy. Backend is deployed and working fine through ECS Fargate DNS name.

But for some reason my domain doesn't work.

1. I've set an A record to my Hosted Zone and attached the ECS Fargate LB:

[image]

2. When I try to access my website it can't load at all:

[image]

3. Proof that my ECS Fargate Load Balancer + custom deployed backend works fine through its DNS name:

[image]

4. Here's my `/modules/ecs/main.tf` written in Terraform:

```
# ECS cluster
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "notes_ecs_cluster" {
    name = "notes-api-dev-cluster"

    tags = {
        Name        = "${var.environment}-ecs-cluster"
        Environment = var.environment
    }
}

# Configure the above ECS Cluster to support FARGATE_SPOT instead of FARGATE
resource "aws_ecs_cluster_capacity_providers" "notes_ecs_cluster_capacity_providers" {
    cluster_name       = aws_ecs_cluster.notes_ecs_cluster.name
    capacity_providers = ["FARGATE_SPOT", "FARGATE"]

    default_capacity_provider_strategy {
        base              = 0
        weight            = 1
        capacity_provider = "FARGATE_SPOT"
    }
}

# For service discovery
resource "aws_service_discovery_http_namespace" "notes_service_discovery_http_namespace" {
    name = aws_ecs_cluster.notes_ecs_cluster.name

    tags = {
        AmazonECSManaged = "true"
    }
}

# Task definition
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "notes_ecs_task_definition" {
    # Task definition configuration
    family = "notes-api-task-definition"

    # Infrastructure requirements
    requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
    network_mode             = "awsvpc"
    execution_role_arn       = "arn:aws:iam::396280700779:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
    cpu                      = "1 vCPU"
    memory                   = "3 GB"

    runtime_platform {
        operating_system_family = "LINUX"
        cpu_architecture        = "X86_64"
    }

    # Container – 1
    container_definitions = jsonencode([
        {
            name         = "notes-api-container"
            image        = "${var.ecr_image_uri}:latest"
            cpu          = 0
            portMappings = [
                {
                    name          = "notes-api-container-8080-tcp",
                    containerPort = 8080
                    hostPort      = 8080,
                    protocol      = "tcp",
                    appProtocol   = "http"
                }
            ],
            essential   = true
            environment = [
                {
                    name  = "AWS_RDS_DATABASE_HOST",
                    value = var.rds_database_host_name
                },
                {
                    name  = "AWS_RDS_DATABASE",
                    value = "notes_db"
                },
                {
                    name  = "AWS_RDS_DATABASE_USERNAME",
                    value = "postgres"
                },
                {
                    name  = "AWS_RDS_DATABASE_PASSWORD",
                    value = "password"
                }
            ],
            environmentFiles = [],
            mountPoints      = [],
            volumesFrom      = [],
            ulimits          = []
        }
    ])

    tags = {
        Name        = "${var.environment}-task-definition"
        Environment = var.environment
    }
}

resource "aws_lb" "notes_lb" {
    name                       = "notes-api-ecs-lb"
    load_balancer_type         = "application"
    security_groups            = [var.notes_lb_security_group_id]
    subnets                    = var.public_subnets_cidr
    enable_deletion_protection = false

    tags = {
        Name        = "${var.environment}-ecs-lb"
        Environment = var.environment
    }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "notes_lb_target_group" {
    name        = "notes-api-ecs-tg"
    protocol    = "HTTP"
    target_type = "ip"
    port        = 8080
    vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

    health_check {
        path                = "/actuator/health"
        protocol            = "HTTP"
        enabled             = true
        interval            = 30
        timeout             = 5
        healthy_threshold   = 10
        unhealthy_threshold = 2
    }

    lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
    }

    tags = {
        Name        = "${var.environment}-ecs-tg"
        Environment = var.environment
    }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "notes_lb_listener" {
    load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.notes_lb.arn
    protocol          = "HTTP"
    port              = 80

    default_action {
        type             = "forward"
        target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.notes_lb_target_group.arn
    }

    lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
    }

    tags = {
        Name        = "${var.environment}-ecs-lb-listener"
        Environment = var.environment
    }
}

# ECS service
resource "aws_ecs_service" "notes_ecs_service" {
    # Deployment configuration
    name                              = "notes-api-service"
    cluster                           = aws_ecs_cluster.notes_ecs_cluster.id
    task_definition                   = aws_ecs_task_definition.notes_ecs_task_definition.arn
    launch_type                       = "FARGATE"
    desired_count                     = 1
    health_check_grace_period_seconds = 0

    # Networking
    network_configuration {
        subnets          = var.private_subnets_cidr
        security_groups  = [var.notes_fargate_security_group_id]
        assign_public_ip = false
    }

    # Load balancing
    load_balancer {
        container_name   = "notes-api-container"
        target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.notes_lb_target_group.arn
        container_port   = 8080
    }

    tags = {
        Name        = "${var.environment}-ecs-service"
        Environment = var.environment
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a DNS error in your browser. The browser isn't finding the record you created in Route53. Use a DNS testing tool like this: https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSCheck.aspx to test if your DNS is configurated and propagated properly.

Comment: @MarkB i just checked via that tool. Everything seems to be in the green and propagated. What else can i try? Any commands? `dig notes-api-...-.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com` command returns `NOERROR` but `dig domain.com` returns `SERVFAIL` error. When i try to `ping` the domain, then "cannot resolve domain.com: Unknown host". If I try to `ping` the LB DNS name, it starts pinging but never receives any packets back, resulting in 100% packet loss

Comment: The computer you are testing from can't get the DNS record for some reason. If the online testing tool says everything is OK, but you can't run `dig` locally to view the domain, then this is a problem with your computer or local network. Try rebooting your computer.

Comment: I get a 404 error page back from your server when I go to that. So it is hitting your API server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255943/discussion-between-busuu-and-mark-b).